# Queues for Custom Objects

Tags: assignment-rules, queue

1) Queue for a Custom Object is already created and added with few internal users. 
 Now, when the records of the custom object is assigned to the Queue, how the members of the queue pick up the record from the queue and assign to themselves?  I mean, where do they go and see the list of records in that queue and assign to themselves?

2) Does Auto-assignment work for custom objects? It works for Case and Lead objects.  Is there any thing in the latest releases for Custom Objects auto-assignment?  I want to automatically assign the custom object records to a particular queue based on criteria.

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

> 1) Queue for a Custom Object is already created and added with few internal users. Now, when the records of the custom object is assigned to the Queue, how the members of the queue pick up the record from the queue and assign to themselves? I mean, where do they go and see the list of records in that queue and assign to themselves?

In the List View, they can select the checkboxes on the side and click the Accept button to transfer the records to themselves (you may need to add this button to your List View Search Layout). You can also create a custom button to add to the page layout itself if you like. You may need to create a List View for the queue, which is available from the object's tab. You'll want to create a Custom Object Tab if you haven't already.

> 2) Does Auto-assignment work for custom objects? It works for Case and Lead objects. Is there any thing in the latest releases for Custom Objects auto-assignment? I want to automatically assign the custom object records to a particular queue based on criteria.

No. While you could build a process/flow/etc for this, there's no built-in feature that mimics assignment rules on Leads/Cases.